# ng-repeat absolute $index when using filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get the absolute $index of the ng-repeat when using the filter. For example I have an array like this:

```
$scope.notes = [
    {
        name: 'note 1',
        value: '1'
    },
    {
        name: 'note 2',
        value: '2'
    },
    {
        name: 'note 3',
        value: '3'
    },
    {
        name: 'note 4',
        value: '4'
    }
];
```

Without applying the filter, the $index refers to the index of each element in the array and I use the $index to the array.

```
note in notes | filter:filterTerm track by $index
```

When I use the expression above the $index gets updated for the new sub-array. Is it possible to get the absolute $index?

Comment: could you assign an 'index' value to your raw data?

Comment: When you look at the $index of each note, what is shown if not the absolute index?

Comment: @haxxxton Unfortunately not :(

Comment: @user1518802 the new index in the sub-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'absolute' $index here. The filter is returning a new array based on the array you passed in and the filter conditions.

Looking how you create your own custom filter makes this a bit easier to understand:

```
app.filter('myfilter',function()
{
  return function( items, filterArg) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      if(item.checkSomething(filterArg) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  };
}
```

Comment: so there are no other way arounds?

Comment: On initalisation of your controller, you could iterate through your array and set a custom property with the original index